# cant access object attributes from js array

Tags: javascript

i have this simple code to get some objects from api and add it to an array

```
 const res = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/cart/carts/"+this.state.user);
  const data = await res.json();
 let data1 = [];
    data.forEach(async item => {
        const res1 = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/storemanger/products/"+item.product);
          const object = await res1.json();
          data1.push(object);
      });
console.log(data1)
```

**output of console log**

[output chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lxhqe.png)

but if try to access first element like

```
console.log(data1[0])
```

**output is** "undefined "

i want to access the productname of objects inside the array

Comment: Try putting console.log(data1) within the foreach after  data1.push(object); and please paste what is the value printed in the console

Comment: you should include what data is btw

Comment: [{…}]
0: {_id: "5ec8ae3e1e6fdd2c24c32e75", productname: "dfdfdfdfdf version3", category: "Mens", price: 49, discount: 55, …}
1: {_id: "5ec8ae3e1e6fdd2c24c32e75", productname: "dfdfdfdfdf version3", category: "Mens", price: 49, discount: 55, …}
2: {_id: "5ec8ae3e1e6fdd2c24c32e75", productname: "dfdfdfdfdf version3", category: "Mens", price: 49, discount: 55, …}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: added an for await version if you're comfortable using more modern syntax

Comment: i tried for await but now im getting an error "item not defined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you prefer `async/await` syntax alternative:

You can use `for await ... of` syntax.

Using json placeholder as an example

```
const response = []

const data = [1,2,3]

for await (item of data) {
  const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/" + item);
  const obj = await res.json()
  response.push(obj)
}

console.log(response) //
```

response at the end yields

```
[
  {userId: 1, id: 1, title: "delectus aut autem", completed: false},
  {userId: 1, id: 2, title: "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui", completed: false},
  {userId: 1, id: 3, title: "fugiat veniam minus", completed: false}
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
let data1 = [];

const promiseArray = data.map(item => fetch("http://localhost:5000/storemanger/products/"+item.product))

Promise.all(promiseArray)
.then(result => Promise.all(result.map(v => v.json()))
.then((values) => {
  data1 = values
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you don't wait for the `fetch` calls to be completed. Since your `forEach` runs an `async` function, the browser will run them asynchronously (this means they will be scheduled to run at some other time). Your code therefore becomes equivalent to:

```js
let data1 = []
console.log(data1)
```

Each of these `fetch` calls return a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/promise). If you want to ensure that `data1` has the required values, you need to wait for the `Promise`s to be fulfilled.

As an example, you can do the following:

```js
const promises = data1.map(url => fetch(url));
Promise.all(promises).then(values => console.log(values));
```

Note that the callback will be called when **all** requests complete. Also note that this code does not take care of handling failed `fetch`es.

Answer (score -1):

You should await .forEach(), but it doesn't exist an async version of .forEach.

Check this: https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404